# Access methods outside jQuery control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery control which has some private methods. I would like to access this methods outside the control. Some code snippet to get more understanding.

These two methods are in same java-script file.

```
function addSiblings(currentbtn) {

    var dvClick = $(currentbtn).closest('div').siblings('div.OrgGroupLists')
    var spnElement = $(dvClick).find('span.bgLime');
    objEditParam.renderRadio = false;
    var dvPrnt =  createDivNode(objEditParam);
    //Want to access "createDivNode" method.
   }

(function ($) {

function createDivNode(objEditParam) {
        var countSpan;
        var dvPrnt = document.createElement("div");
        countSpan = OS_hdnCount;
        dvPrnt.id = "dv_Pr_" + countSpan;
}

})(jQuery);
```

How can i call the method.

Comment: why not put both inside? i might guess you are using inline events like "onclick(this)" am i right?

Comment: You cannot do this, change your architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function ($) {

    //use an event handler instead
    $('element_selector').on('click',function(){

        //call the function and passing it the target
        addSiblings(this);
    })

    function addSiblings(currentbtn) {
        var dvClick = $(currentbtn).closest('div').siblings('div.OrgGroupLists')
        var spnElement = $(dvClick).find('span.bgLime');
        objEditParam.renderRadio = false;
        var dvPrnt =  createDivNode(objEditParam);

        //you can now access createDivNode()
    }

    function createDivNode(objEditParam) {
        var countSpan;
        var dvPrnt = document.createElement("div");
        countSpan = OS_hdnCount;
        dvPrnt.id = "dv_Pr_" + countSpan;
    }

})(jQuery);
```